# How to use doc.getElementbyClassName to find if one if its elements is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML table which acts as an invoice. It gets generated for me to then download and print it off. However some of the elements can be empty for various reasons which causes the whole row to align right/left because there is missing text. So i want to write a bit of code to check if an element is empty and if it is, put some whitespace there.

This is the table.

```
<div class="invoiceTable">
  <div class="titles2" style="padding-top: 15px;padding-bottom: 15px;">
    <div class="invoice-qty">Qty</div>

    <div class="invoice-loc">Loc</div>
    <div class="invoice-items">Items</div>
    <div class="invoice-cus">Stock</div>
    <div class="invoice-id">Item ID</div>
    <div class="invoice-ais" style="text-align: right;">2loc</div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <!--START: items-->
  <div class="row" style="border-bottom: solid;border-width: 1px;padding-top: 15px;padding-bottom: 15px;">
    <div class="invoice-qty">[numitems]</div>
    <div class="invoice-loc">[warehouse_location]</div>
    <div class="invoice-items">[itemname]</div>
    <!--START: warehouse_location-->

    <div class="invoice-cus" style="text-align:center;">[warehouse_custom]</div>
    <div class="invoice-id" style="text-align:center;">[id]</div>
    <div class="invoice-ais" style="text-align:center;">[warehouse_aisle]</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!--END: warehouse_location-->
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm wanting at the moment to test if the bit of the row 'invoice-ais' is empty.

I have the following script which is also checking if it is empty and then outputting to the console a message. In my mind i need to  loop through all the elements of the invoice-ais class and check to see if they are empty.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var doc = document.getElementsByClassName('invoice-ais');

  for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++) {
    if (doc.getElementById(i) == '') {
      console.log("empty");
    }
  }
});
```

Which gives the following error.

> doc.getElementById is not a function

Comment: Adding whitespaces isn't addressing the alignment issue but only works around it. This sounds like a job for CSS, apply fixed min widths , max widths and similar, what ever you desire. You should maybe do a test page with just the markup and no data and then use CSS to make it look the way you like. Then add the data and enhance the CSS to adapt with max widths or scrolling, etc..

Comment: I have formatted your code **John**, you can see the  [**Formatting Docs**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more details on how to format questions. There is also a [**code snipped tool**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) you can use if needed.

Comment: Thankyou very much for pointing me to that I never knew. Will use that in future OP.  Sorry for my OP post being such a mess.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because you're trying to use `getElementById` with the result of `getElementsByName` which returns a `NodeList Collection`.

```
var doc = document.getElementsByClassName('invoice-ais');
```

**Important:** The HTML can contain entities like this `&nbsp;` which represents a space.  Thus, you need to read about attribute `textContent` and jQuery function `.text()`

**You're using jQuery, so do this:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.invoice-ais').each(function() {
     // Important, here you're comparing HTML.  Please read about the function .text()
    if ($(this).html().trim() === '') {
      console.log("empty");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="invoiceTable">
  <div class="titles2" style="padding-top: 15px;padding-bottom: 15px;">

    <div class="invoice-qty">Qty</div>

    <div class="invoice-loc">Loc</div>
    <div class="invoice-items">Items</div>
    <div class="invoice-cus">Stock</div>
    <div class="invoice-id">Item ID</div>
    <div class="invoice-ais" style="text-align: right;">2loc</div>
    <div class="invoice-ais" style="text-align: right;"></div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <!--START: items-->
  <div class="row" style="border-bottom: solid;border-width: 1px;padding-top: 15px;padding-bottom: 15px;">
    <div class="invoice-qty">[numitems]</div>
    <div class="invoice-loc">[warehouse_location]</div>
    <div class="invoice-items">[itemname]</div>
    <!--START: warehouse_location-->

    <div class="invoice-cus" style="text-align:center;">[warehouse_custom]</div>
    <div class="invoice-id" style="text-align:center;">[id]</div>
    <div class="invoice-ais" style="text-align:center;">[warehouse_aisle]</div>


    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!--END: warehouse_location-->
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: That worked a treat, thankyou very much. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You should access one particular element with `doc[i]`, and then you could check the `textContent` property, and apply  `trim` to it so white space doesn't count as anything:

```
if (doc[i].textContent.trim() === '') { // it's empty
    doc[i].innerHTML = '&nbsp;'; // add a non-breaking space as content.
}
```

But if this is what you want to do to align a table, then you're on the wrong path. Instead, use a `table`, `tr` and `td` tags which behave like that automatically (even if no content). You can also achieve this with CSS while keeping the `div` tags you have.

Here is CSS which brings the table-style alignment:

```
.invoiceTable {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.titles2, .row {
    display:table-row;
}
.invoice-qty, .invoice-loc, .invoice-cus, .invoice-id, .invoice-ais, .invoice-items {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: But, the OP wants to check the HTML, can you make a mention about that? i.e: HTML entities `&nbsp;`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. The code works a treat, I will try the CSS as well to see if that's any better. This may be a stupid question but is there a reason why i should avoid using javascript/jQuery for this sort of stuff?

Comment: The only concern is that trying to align things through adding spaces is unreliable, as this depends heavily on font properties. And even if it aligns in one browser, it may not in the other. Even in the same, it may distort as soon as you change the zoom-level.